# ошибка в установлении библиотеки

Tags: python-3.x, pip

в общем, устанавливаю библиотеку wxPython и у меня ошибка, сначала обновил pip installer, позже выяснилась еще 1 ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Или подождите, пока исправят и опубликуют прекомпилированную версию для Python 3.11, или просто используйте Python 3.10

Comment: Не спешите так переходить на самую новую версию Python. 3.11 выпущена в релиз меньше месяца назад, не все библиотеки еще обновлены под эту версию (я подозреваю, что даже под 3.10 еще не все могли обновить).